# split string vba

Tags: excel, vba, string

I'm looking to split the string that the codes gives me.
The output of the code is for example, "DPJobState-02-Mar-2020" then "DPJobState-03-Mar-2020" and so on, I want to have as an output only "02-Mar-2020" for that worksheet

```
Dim contador As Integer
contador = 2
Dim result As Workbook
Set result = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\apractica\Desktop\Macro\Durst\ResultadosDurst.xlsm")
Dim m_2 As Variant

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    result.Worksheets(1).Cells(contador, 1).Value = ws.name
    contador = contador + 1
Next
```

Comment: What have you tried and where is the problem?

Comment: `Split("DPJobState-02-Mar-2020","-",2)(1)`.

Comment: Will the date format always be "dd-mmm-yyyy"?

Comment: yes, but I need it just as string

Comment: Then I'd just use `Right$` as proposed in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function). If you want two substrings returned, make the *limit* argument `2`, and then use `(1)` to return the 2nd substring.

So with your example:

```
 Split("DPJobState-02-Mar-2020","-",2)(1)
```

The resulting two substrings are

- "DPJobState"
- "02-Mar-2020"

And `(1)` returns the 2nd since this is a zero-based array.

Though maybe more simply, if your sheet names always end with a date formatted as "dd-mmm-yyyy", then you could just use `Right$`:

```
result.Worksheets(1).Cells(contador, 1).Value = Right$(ws.name, 11)
```

Comment: @BigBen what is the purpose of 2?

Comment: @Error1004 See [HERE](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/split.php)

Comment: @Error1004 - "If you want *two* substrings returned..." :-)